# Unable to get Layer mask of UIButton to work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calayer

I am unable to mask a UIButton. It's working for a UIView but not for a UIButton.

My code is pretty simple:

```
let maskingLayer = CALayer()
maskingLayer.frame = backToLiveButton.bounds
let maskingImage = WxStyleKit.imageOfTimelineBackToLiveArrow(backToLiveButton.bounds)
maskingLayer.contents = maskingImage.CGImage
backToLiveButton.layer.mask = maskingLayer
```

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is the WxStyleKit from paintcode?

Comment: yes, WxStyleKit is from paintcode

Comment: Can you post the code for relevant part of the StyleKit so that I and others can test it?

Comment: @Ike10 ny PaintCode is too big... :) just load an image using UIImage(named: "maskingImage")"

Comment: Is the button coming through completely visible or completely hidden?  Does your image have a solid or transparent background?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work with a `@IBOutlet` are you opposed to a programmatically created UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the masking to work by subclassing `UIButton` and overriding `drawRect`. There are two options to get this to work, either have an image to turn into a `UIImage` or modify the PaintCode function to return the `UIBezierPath` and use a `CAShapeLayer`.

## Option 1: Using a Predefined Image

```
class MaskedButton: UIButton {

  @IBInspectable var imageString: String?

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    if let imageString = imageString {
      let maskImage = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: imageString)
      let maskImageView = UIImageView(frame: rect)
      maskImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      maskImageView.image = maskImage
      layer.mask = maskImageView.layer
    }
  }

}
```

In this method, the imageString property is set in Interface Builder and is the name of an image in Assets.xcassets.

## Option 2: Using a Dynamically Created UIBezierPath

```
class MaskedButton: UIButton {

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = Wx.drawCanvas1(frame: rect).cgPath
    layer.mask = maskLayer
  }

}
```

#### The Modified PaintCode Function

```
public class Wx : NSObject {

   //// Drawing Methods

   public class func drawCanvas1(frame: CGRect) -> UIBezierPath {

       //// Bezier Drawing
       let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
       bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 8.88, y: frame.minY + 28.28))
       bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 77.2, y: frame.minY + 1.57), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 32.99, y: frame.minY + 2.6), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 63.13, y: frame.minY - 4.59))
       ...
       bezierPath.close()

       return bezierPath
    }

}
```

This method works but, unfortunately, you would have to make a subclass for each type of button because it relies on the having the function inside the `drawRect` override. I don't know of any way to dynamically set a function call, but I hope this helps!

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!